# What does adverb "proper" really mean?

Tags: word-meaning

I came across the word "proper" while reading a random comment on a video about WW2 Japanese history on YouTube.

> Showing even more dedication to their ideology was when Americans started landing on Japan ***proper***, both civilians and soldiers committed suicide rather than be taken prisoner.

I looked the word up on Lexico.com. This what it gave:

> part of speech: adverb, British informal dialect, definition--satisfactorily or correct

At first, I thought *proper* meant exactly like the Lexico entry said but I was still confused.

Next, I looked up the word in the Collins Dictionary and I got this:

> You can add *proper* after a word to indicate that you are referring to the central and most important part of a place, event, or object and want to distinguish it from other things that are not regarded as being important or central to it.
>
> Example: *A distinction must be made between archaeology proper and science-based archaeology*

I still am confused. Please explain what the word "proper" means, whether in the context of the YouTube comment or in a general context.

Answer (score 14):

This use is the sense described in Collins.  It is an adjective, but unlike most adjectives, it is placed after the noun.  Lexico has the definition:

> 1.1 *postpositive* Strictly so called; in its true form.

Postpositive is a technical term, meaning "placed after". This definition is not very clear, and the Collins definition is better: It means the "real Japan" (and not outlying islands or Japanese colonies).

The adverbal use is very casual, and comes after a verb.  "He talks proper"  to mean "He talks properly or correctly". If you say "He talks proper" then you are not talking proper at all!

Comment: Good point about its adverbial use. I bet _that's_ what used to annoy Prime Mover's parents.

Comment: I guess the OP thought it was modifying "landing", hence the conclusion that it was an adverb.

Comment: If it helps, another postpositive is "general" as in "attorney general". So the plural is technically "attorneys general" instead of "attorney generals" (though either is fine colloquially). IIRC, English picked this up from French, where most adjectives go after the noun.

Comment: However, the postpositive placement of "proper" does not seem to be related to the French cognate.  In French, "propre" means "clean" or "own".

Comment: @JamesK I think the remark about French was in reference to "attorney general" specifically, rather than English postpositive adjectives in general.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.  Many of these postpositives are borrowing from French.  But not this one.

Comment: @JamesK Old French _propre_ seems itself to be borrowed from Latin _proprius_ (related to ownership, "property") which is also of course used postpositively (though I don't understand the semantic shift to "clean").

Answer (score 8):

***Proper*** is nearly always employed as an adjective. ***Properly*** would be its associated adverb.

But the particular adjectival sense in which it is used here is a special one where it appears as a post-modifier. **It is OED sense 7c(b)**.

> (b) As postmodifier, designating the part or aspect of a larger entity
> that is most accurately so called.

The first example is from 1796:

> 1796   D. MacPherson Geogr. Illustr. Sc. Hist.   Albany, Albania,
> Scotland, strictly speaking the country between the Forth and the
> Spey, or Scotland proper.

More recent examples are:

> 1975   Countryman Autumn 30   Apart from the garden proper, there is a
> great area to the north which is being planted with trees.
>
> 2005   Yorks. Evening Post (Nexis) 18 Jan.   US favourites like
> meatloaf, BBQ chicken with fried yams, [etc.],..are all on a
> three-course menu of soul food that's being served up before the music
> proper gets under way.

**In the OP's example *Japan proper* clearly means the area of Japan itself, as opposed to its outlying possessions.**

Comment: TIL, Edinburgh, Glasgow and Loch Ness are not in "Scotland proper"!

Comment: @JamesK This was 1796 - the time of the Highland clearances. What different parties regarded as constituting "Scotland proper" was, I suppose, quite a mobile matter.

Comment: Are we talking about the 'no true Scots place' fallacy here?

Answer (score 3):

The word 'proper' has more than one meaning. It can be an adjective, meaning (e.g.) 'real, satisfactory, suitable, or correct', 'showing standards of behaviour that are socially and morally acceptable', or 'complete'.

The word also has a separate meaning when used, **usually after** a noun, in this case the name of a country: 'belonging to the main, most important, or typical part'. This is the meaning you have seen in the Youtube comment.

During the Second World War, American military forces fought against
the Empire of Japan, following the attack by the latter on Pearl
Harbor. First the Americans attacked and defeated Japanese forces in
territories and occupied areas outside Japan, then in 1945 they
advanced to the edge of what Japanese people considered their homeland
area (and not colonies), for example Iwo Jima, in the Nanpo Shoto
Islands which are administratively, part of Tokyo, next, Okinawa.
These were **Japan proper**.

Other examples:

> Before **the meal proper** begins at Silk, Frankfurt's most futuristic
> restaurant, you're handed a ceramic spoon containing what appears to
> be the yolk of an egg.
>
> Before **the concert proper** Nico Muhly and friends played an
> introduction to the first set of songs.
>
> As soon as you're unpacked and have found the right bed for you, **the
> holiday proper** can begin!
>
> A swathe of wasteland follows and then, further along, comes **the town proper**.

Comment: Is it worth pointing out that this usage is idiomatic and possibly colloquial? I remember being taught (by my uber-snobbishly-correct parents and teachers) that "proper" in this context was slang and therefore as unacceptable as using "mac" for "mackinosh" or saying "bloody".

Comment: @PrimeMover - Really? Oxford doesn't call the definition _strictly so called; in its true form_ colloquial, and I've never heard anyone suggest that it is 'slang'.

Comment: @PrimeMover - There is _nothing colloquial whatsoever_ about this specialised geo/political usage. It is very common in e.g. town planning discussions, e.g. about the regions around London that, although not administratively part of that, are bound to it: 'these areas are definitely not ‘London’ proper but part of its wider economic sphere of influence.' Nothing colloquial there. Maybe you're think about e.g. 'Learn to talk proper'?

Comment: @KateBunting Okay, just put this down to me having mad fascist snobs as parents.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey See the above comment to Kate

Comment: @PrimeMover Are you sure it wasn't "_I felt a proper charlie_" they called colloquial?

Comment: @OldBrixtonian That as well. But also "proper" used in the specific context of this question, which is where we came in. Interesting to learn that it's "proper English" after all. Looks like there's yet more piles of burning coal to be piled onto their eternal souls.

Comment: @PrimeMover Perhaps you weren't the _easiest_ child in the world... :-)

Comment: @OldBrixtonian Now let's not get *personal* here

Comment: @PrimeMover - I too suffered as you did, although the attack was two-pronged: the infant and junior schools tried to eradicate grammatical solecisms like 'there's two apples on the table', whereas with my parents it was mostly pronunciation and accent, dropped aitches, glottal stops, etc. My mother: 'Don't say 'ain't', say 'isn't' and 'Say cake, not 'cike'. I do recall, when I was very little, an aged great-aunt, who, I fancy, talked like a mixture of Sam Weller and Dot Cotton's granny. Not to be emulated, it was quietly made clear. The nervousness of the lower middle classes of that era.

Comment: @PrimeMover - apposite joke. A father overhears his son using a bad word while playing with a pal. Father: Don't say that word! Son: But, Dad, Charles Dickens uses the word 'bastard'. Father: Well, don't f***ing play with him then!

Comment: @MichaelHarvey This usage is not restricted to places and geography, as the OED 2005 example (in my answer) illustrates. "This is just a warm-up act, before the entertainment proper begins" is a perfectly viable use.

Comment: @PrimeMover - in many ways, I was that boy!

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Heh. "Say white, not woite." Armageddon happened when my sister and I and a friend were sitting in the garden playing "posh ladies": "Would you laike some waine, or some sherraie ...?" and the egg-donor overheard. And when I started to imitate the speech habits of the local village kids in rural Gloucestershire so as to at least *try* to fit in ... "Mummy, Prime said 'deown' today ..." We can of course laugh now.

Comment: @PrimeMover My mother wasn't quite that bad. I suspect if I and others had been playing 'posh people', she would have laughed and called 'You silly buggers!' through the window. The problem was my father mainly.